# Compare list item properties in Drools when condition

Tags: drools

I have inserted list of elements in StatefulKnowledgeSession. Now in When clause in drools .drl file I need to compare some propertiy values of different elements of the list.

For example, I have a list of pets [ added in session as kbSession.insert(list) ]  where each pet has a name property (pet1.name = "adi", pet2.name="flix"). So what would be best for checking this items in when clause?

Say in my test.drl file I have

rule "pet items"

dialect "java"

when

```
 list.get(0).name != list.get(1).name
```

then

```
 do something!
```

Any suggesstion is greatly appreciated!

Kind Regards,

Shekh

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to validate all your Pet objects (technical right term - Facts) against a rule? Then you do not need insert it as List. Insert all the Pet objects one by one as session.insert(petObj) and fireAllRules. The Rules Engine will check all objects against rule and then activate the rule for the matching object(s).

Comment: Thanks gammay for your reply. Well, i have some restriction on rules like no-loop and Lock-on-active are true. So i need to way to check fact list (list will be inserted in session) item property values in rule. Thanks again for your reply.